# Не отображается фавиконка!

Tags: html, css, github

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Странная делюга.
Работаю через вс код. Есть иконка, лежит в папке со всеми img, подключаю ее

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="img/favicon.ico">
```

Запускаю просмотр проекта через плагин Live Server, все норм, фавикон отображается. Когда залил все файлы на гитхаб, иконка перестала отображаться по ссылке на репозиторий, пробовал на всех устройствах в доме и на всех браузерах - один хрен.

Линк на проект - https://worldwarmworm.github.io/webdev/

Есть проект, где по такой же схеме подключал фавикон, там все отображается. Вот и на него линк: https://worldwarmworm.github.io/lawfirm`введите сюда код`/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так этой иконки даже нету в папке с изображениями. Подставь другое изображение которое есть в папке, например, href="img/about-ico-1.png", все работает

Comment: Почему нету? я заскринил выше. или нет на гит хабе?

Comment: На гитхабе ее не было реально, хотя заливал весь проект без исключения. Ну пох, залил эту иконку. все равно она не отображается

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">`

Answer (score 0):

у тебя оно так ``` html

````
поскольку у тебя favicon.ico , то и тут надо ставить x-image/ico а не png
вот пример
``` html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> //ICO
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-png"> // PNG
````